# Distinguish Intranet and external IP addresses in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm writing a browser add-on (Chrome and Firefox) which, in a nutshell, does "some calculations" based upon the content of **each page the user visits** (i.e. we're not talking about the user's *own* pages), presenting the user with a score. In the case of particularly high scores, the page title, page URL, etc. is submitted (automatically) to a central service so that a kind of league table can be shown.

All of this works perfectly, but I want - where possible - to **strip out all traffic** from the pages of Intranets that our users happen to visit. (We don't store or transmit any page content, nonetheless there are privacy concerns, and we don't want anything to do with internal / corporate documents.)

In theory I can work out (to a reasonable degree of accuracy) whether an IP is likely to be from an intranet @ [Distinguish the between intranet and official IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601602/distinguish-the-between-intranet-and-official-ip-addresses), but as the DOM doesn't provide access to the document's host IP, is it practical to try to determine the IP on the fly and then apply those IP rules, given the possibility that lookup services might be down/slow?

Would a simpler alternative - like pattern-matching for the TLD of the document's hostname - be nearly as good?

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

I was about to answer this myself with *"I'll just do the IP check on the server, when the page stats are submitted, and only complete the submission if the IP is not within the internal range - it's much easier."* ... unfortunately I can't do this: because my back-end is Google AppEngine [Java] and the `InetAddress` class is restricted, I can't do arbitrary IP lookups.

Comment: Anyone can change their hosts file to point a domain at localhost, I have no idea how you will filter this out as checking a domain from some other source will not reflect my own hosts file.

Comment: True, though I'm not so worried about the 0.1% case - this doesn't have to be bulletproof, as I'm not capturing sensitive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [nsIDNSService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDNSService) to resolve the host name in Firefox. Along these lines:

```js
var threadManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1"]
                              .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIThreadManager);
var dnsService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/dns-service;1"]
                           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIDNSService);
var listener = {
  onLookupComplete: function(request, record, status)
  {
    if (Components.isSuccessCode(status))
      alert("Host IP address: " + record.getNextAddrAsString());
    else
      alert("Lookup failed");
  }
};
dnsService.asyncResolve("www.google.com", 0, listener,
                        threadManager.currentThread);
```

This is usually a very fast operation because the host name is already cached. Note: if you use the Add-on SDK then you will have to [use chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) and replace access to `Components` properties by the respective aliases.

As to Chrome, I doubt that you can solve this problem properly there. As Korvin Szanto notes in his comment, *any* host name could point to a local address. And Chrome won't let you get the IP address that it talks to.

Comment: Thanks for this. My idea of doing it all on the server has been stymied by Google App Engine not allowing DNS lookups, so I am going to use your suggestion on Firefox (just got it working now), and will perform asynchronous lookups using the http://smart-ip.net/geoip-api service on Chrome.