# Arbitrary host / IP lookups on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http

I'm developing a browser plugin (see [Distinguish Intranet and external IP addresses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505450/distinguish-intranet-and-external-ip-addresses-in-javascript)) that (in a nutshell) generates "scores" for every page a user visits, asynchronously submitting details about the highest scores to the back-end server, which is an App Engine instance. (This all works fine.)

I want the IP *for the host the user originally requested* (so that I can strip out 'intranet' IPs) - but because it's somewhere between fiddly and impossible to get that on the client-side in a cross-browser way, I thought I'd send the page URL along with our AJAX call to the server and do the lookup there, using the JDK's `InetAddress` class,. Unfortunately this class is blocked on App Engine.

Is there an *alternate* HTTP library I could use to perform host -> IP lookups there, i.e. that doesn't go through `InetAddress` ?

And if there is, and I can indeed bypass the JDK restriction, is this legal / ethical / a sane approach?

Comment: You're asking about an 'HTTP library', but what you're trying to do is a DNS lookup, not an HTTP request.

Comment: True, I should have said 'networking' library. Not sure if that would have made a difference - either way I'm doing the lookups on the client now (cached DNS entries on Firefox, remote web service on Chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to do DNS lookup directly from App Engine atm: see (and star!) the following [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=354).